# PIG Store function: storing only certain fields is possible?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a use case where I only need to store certain fields to HDFS. I know I can do some foreach and so on to preserve fields of interest but I am wondering whether this is doable in Store function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible using your custom `Store` function: http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449302641/load_and_store_funcs.html

But in general it is much easier to use `GENERATE` and store desired fields in some other tuple, that will be used only in `STORE` function